# DISTINCT AND COUNT

Tags: sql

There is a column of Country Code and another 3 column with MEDALS GOLD,SILVER, and BRONZE
I want to Show The total of GOLD,SILVER, and BRONZE Medals they have got for each country,

Graph look like this

```
COUNTRY_ISOCODE  PART_GOLD PART_SILVER PART_BRONZE
--------------- ---------- ----------- -----------
AUS                      2           0           0 
AUS                      2           0           3 
AUS                      0           0           0 
ZAF                      0           0           0 
ZAF                      1           1           0
```

But i want it be like this

```
COUNTRY_ISOCODE  PART_GOLD PART_SILVER PART_BRONZE
--------------- ---------- ----------- -----------
AUS                      4           0           0 
ZAF                      1           1           0
```

Comment: are you talking about excel ?? then which chart is this ??

Comment: What do `DISTINCT` and `COUNT` have to do with this? It looks like you want to have the sum rather than the count. What queries did you already try?

Comment: Your answer set doesn't match the data: AUS PART_BRONZE should be 3?

Comment: Basically i want to make it DISTINCT for COUNTRY ISOCODE and  it counts each Medal for the countryif you know what i mean

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you *do* talk about SQL (as implied by `count` and `distinct`):

```
select country_isocode, 
       sum(part_gold) as part_gold, 
       sum(part_silver) as part_silver,
       sum(part_bronze) as part_bronze
from the_table
group by country_isocode;
```